# Gtk+ glade file

Tags: c++, gtk, gnu

I'm developing a program in gtk+ with glade and I load the interface doing,

```
    GtkBuilder *builder;
gtk_builder_add_from_file(builder, "test.glade", NULL);
```

I'm used to Visual c++ WINAPI and I don't have many experience with gtk.I was wondering if I can assemble `.glade` files in my executable. Thanks.

Comment: Is LiMars answer good enough for you?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, it's possible using gtk_builder_add_from_string() but then you should include your glade file conents in form of C string like.

The common practice is to NOT build in you glade files into binaries (like you did with resources of Windows). This allows you as a developer to change GUI without recompiling the binary.